# Error with <a href="url">link text</a> code that

Tags: html, href

The below code suddenly stopped working today. For some reason, both the Facebook and Twitter links combine the text I want to display with the link itself. This causes the links to have no text displayed when viewing in the browser.

I can't tell the difference between the links that display properly and the links that do not.

Is there something I am missing?

```
<div align="center"> 

<a href="http://deondon.com/">Home</a> -
<a href="http://deondon.com/tribe/“ target="_blank">Subscribe</a> - 
<a href="http://deondon.com/contact/ “ target="_blank">Contact</a> - 
<a href="http://deondon.com/followme/“>Facebook</a> - 
<a href="http://deondon.com/followme/“>Instagram</a> - 
<a href="http://deondon.com/followme/“>Twitter</a> - 
<a href="http://deondon.com/followme/“>LinkedIn</a><br>
&copy; Copyright 2016 by Deon Don.<br>

 </div>
```

[image]

Comment: It's because your end-quotes aren't standard `"` - you are instead using `“`. Replace these and it will work. Voting to close as this is a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Your quote is not the regular quote that is supposed to close it. If you look at your question, you see how the quote after `followme/` is irregular. Just copy/paste or type in a regular quote to make it right.

```
<div align="center"> 

<a href="http://deondon.com/">Home</a> -
<a href="http://deondon.com/tribe/" target="_blank">Subscribe</a> - 
<a href="http://deondon.com/contact/ " target="_blank">Contact</a> - 
<a href="http://deondon.com/followme/">Facebook</a> - 
<a href="http://deondon.com/followme/">Instagram</a> - 
<a href="http://deondon.com/followme/">Twitter</a> - 
<a href="http://deondon.com/followme/">LinkedIn</a><br>
&copy; Copyright 2016 by Deon Don.<br>

</div>
```

You possibly may have switched your keyboard to another language.

Comment: Omg Thank you! it was driving me crazy for the last 15 mins. That fixed it.

Comment: @DeonDon.Com You're welcome! Please accept my answer if it answered your question.

Answer (score -1):

I agree about the quoting mark isn't the only reason !
You've also written a space in the link:

Error:
Contact -

Valuable :
Contact -

No link in the world contains a space.
That little space could be that nuclear in your programming.

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing how you example relates to the code in the original question. I would recommend copy/pasting at least one full line from the original code and showing how to fix it.